# Apache log4php documentation: "Note that" - what?

Tags: log4php

In the documentation for log4php (at http://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/appender/layout.html) there is the following line for the linebreak token in the layout pattern:

```
 %n A line break. Note that
```

... and that's it! What should the rest of the line say?

(I think it's a reference to the linebreak character being \n or \r\n depending on the native OS.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an error, "Note that" should have been removed. My guess is, it has not been corrected when the docs are ported from log4j to log4php.

log4php transforms %n with PHP_EOL. This should use lineendings in a crossplattfrom friendly way

(see also: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4php/trunk/src/main/php/helpers/LoggerPatternParser.php?view=markup )

Hope that helped!

Cheers
Christian

Answer (score 0):

The text is actually:

> Note that a line break will not be printed unless explicitely specified.

From: http://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/layouts/pattern.html